# Is the following sentence, in terms of its adjectival declension, right?

Tags: grammatical-case, declension

> Hast du gestern **ein nützliches** Buch gekauft?

I know when it comes to declension of adjectives in German, they tend to wear pretty much the same case form as that of their preceding articles such as, "Der **kleine Hund** ist schön." or "Ich bin heute Morgen **aus dem tiefen Schlaf** aufgewacht.".
Nevertheless, indefinite and possessive articles tend to have some exceptions to their rules, that for example in case of neutral nouns in the accusative position, *-es* is attached to the end of the preceding modifying adjective.

I have just started learning German as my third language, and in as much as I have always been so pernickety about proper application of grammatical rules, I would like to ensure that what I produce is syntactically sound and good and I do appreciate your time and effort to elucidate what might seem so elementary and easy to know.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into this question but still I don't know what more to answer than "It's correct", making this a case of proof reading. Why would you doubt the sentence? You seem to the rules so what exactly makes you uncertain?

Comment: More accurate than "tend to wear the form of the preceding articles" is "there are three forms of adjective declension, sometimes called *weak*, *strong* and *mixed*, where strong and to some degree mixed endings look like the article endings". The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives#Weak_and_strong_inflection) has details. Was that your question?

Comment: You say that indefinite and possessive articles tend to have some exceptions. I'm not sure what you refer to, because there are no exceptions, not even some. The declension is always equal. I wonder if you might not be familiar with [weak, strong and mixed declension](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/index.html?MenuId=Word313#Anchor-Deklinationstypen-35882)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the weak & strong thing...yeah that's what I have been unaware of...now with a bit of practice I will manage to make sense of it..

Comment: Community voted to put this question on hold. Unfortunately this was done whithout saying why and what to improve. My impression is that it might be from its poor title. To get it reopened please [edit] the title, and possibly the question to elaborate better what your issue/question is. Also see http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/492/should-we-leave-a-comment-when-closing-a-question

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker I can assure you your sentence is grammatically correct. The case is singular (one book), neutrum (das Buch) and accusative (object only acting passively). Read this [Flexikon](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:n%C3%BCtzlich) for all kinds of declensions.